# How to search a specific country's tweets with Tweepy client.search_recent_tweets()

Tags: python, tweepy, twitterapi-python

y'all. I'm trying to figure out how to sort for a specific country's tweets using search_recent_tweets. I take a country name as input, use pycountry to get the 2-character country code, and then I can either put some sort of location filter in my query or in search_recent_tweets params. Nothing I have tried so far in either has worked.

```
######

import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import API
import pycountry as pyc

# upload token
BEARER_TOKEN='XXXXXXXXX'

# get tweets
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=BEARER_TOKEN)
# TAKE USER INPUT
countryQuery = input("Find recent tweets about travel in a certain country (input country name): ")

keyword = 'women safe'  # gets tweets containing women and safe for that country (safe will catch safety)

# get country code to plug in as param in search_recent_tweets
country_code = str(pyc.countries.search_fuzzy(countryQuery)[0].alpha_2)

# get 100 recent tweets containing keywords and from location = countryQuery
query = str(keyword+' place_country='+str(countryQuery)+' -is:retweet')  # search for keyword and no retweets
posts = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, max_results=100, tweet_fields=['id', 'text', 'entities', 'author_id'])
# expansions=geo.place_id, place.fields=[country_code],
# filter posts to remove retweets

# export tweets to json
import json
with open('twitter.json', 'w') as fp:
    for tweet in posts.data:
        json.dump(tweet.data, fp)
        fp.write('\n')
        print("* " + str(tweet.text))
```

**I have tried variations of:**

```
query = str(keyword+' -is:retweet')  # search for keyword and no retweets
posts = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, place_fields=[str(countryQuery), country_code], max_results=100, tweet_fields=['id', 'text', 'entities', 'author_id'])
```

**and:**

```
query = str(keyword+' place.fields='+str(countryQuery)+','+country_code+' -is:retweet')  # search for keyword and no retweets
posts = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, max_results=100, tweet_fields=['id', 'text', 'entities', 'author_id'])
```

These either ended up pulling me NoneType tweets aka nothing or causing a
"The `place.fields` query parameter value [Germany] is not one of [contained_within,country,country_code,full_name,geo,id,name,place_type]"

The documentation for search_recent_tweets seems like place.fields / place_fields / place_country should be supported.

Any advice would help!!!

Comment: I'm under the impression that you want to use `place_fields` as a _filter_ (maybe I'm wrong): If so, that's not what it is supposed to do. It just determines what data the response contains, structurally, not content-wise. You have to filter afterwards. In my experience (which is ofc limited) the place fields are usually missing. You could check if the `annotations` in the `entities` contains an entry with `type` `"Place"`.

Comment: a small amount of tweet only has geo coordinates so, it is hard too find get information by search_recent_tweets(). it is possible to location search by `snscrape`'s  twitter-search with `geocode` but it is not guarantee to sent from real location. detail is [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/definitive-way-to-search-tweets-by-country-code/131851)